# Why Laravel5.4 $request->cookie('key') is empty when PHP global var $_COOKIE has cookies

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to read the cookies in Laravel5.4. So I get the cookies after successful validation with third party Authorization server. I am not making the cookies in laravel5.4, but I am reading the cookie value send to me from view/frontend. I can see the values of cookies in Chrome debugger environment as well as from PHP global variable $_COOKIE. They are all set correctly.

However, when I tried to read the same cookie using $request->cookie('key') from controller method... it shows nothing. I also tried Cookie facade to read the value and still nothing. This controller is handling a redirect route which is called by the third party oauth server and this server when it redirects to my URL, it also sets the cookies.

**Am I not setting this redirect url route correctly in web.php file in Laravel5.4?** This is how it is defined in web.php as below:

> Route::get('login/okta/callback',
>   'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');

The request object is empty when I dumped the content but $_COOKIE has the data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Laravel's cookie class encrypts and decrypts the values of its cookies (see the `App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies` middleware). When you have it look at a cookie it didn't set, it's going to try (and fail) to decrypt it.

If you've got a cookie set from outside Laravel, use `$_COOKIE` to work with it, or add the name of the cookie to the `$except` array in `app/Http/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php` so it isn't messed with.

Comment: ceejayoz - BTW could you please provide some explanation for your first paragraph? I am not quite able to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Andy By default, Laravel encrypts all cookies. This also means that it attempts to decrypt all cookies—even ones that didn't come from Laravel. 

When you try to access a third party cookie, Laravel thinks it should decrypt it when bringing it back through the request. The result of the decryption is invalid, so you end up with an empty string.

By adding the cookie to the `$except` array, you are telling your Laravel application that you don't want that particular cookie to be encrypted or decrypted.

Comment: In config/cookie.php just `return  ['encryption' => ['enabled' => true, 'except' => ['no', 'encryption', 'for', 'these']];` then `$request->cookie('these')` will no longer be null, instead it will show the un-encrypted value that you would find in `$_COOKIE['these']`.

Comment: @FrankForte Interesting, I didn't know that existed. Neat find!